# How to join from 3 table with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 table inside my database, my first table is person table its store all person name, my second table is hobby table its store all hobby of all person,the third table is referensi table store all references person and hobby.

```
Tabel person :               Tabel hobby :            Tabel referensi :

-----------------      ------------------    -------------------------------------
|  id  |  name  |      |  id  |  hobby  |    |  id  |  ref_person  |  ref_hobby  |
-----------------      ------------------    -------------------------------------
|   1  |  Rose  |      |   1  |  Makan  |    |   1  |    1         |    1        |
|   2  |  Lisa  |      |   2  |  Renang |    |   2  |    1         |    3        |
|   3  |  Jisoo |      |   3  |  Nyanyi |    |   3  |    1         |    4        |
|   4  |  Jennie|      |   4  |  Youtube|    |   4  |    3         |    5        |
-----------------      |   5  |  Masak  |    -------------------------------------
                       ------------------


I want to count all hobby by that person

Example I want select Rose :          Or I want select Jisoo :

---------------------------                    ---------------------------
|  id  |  hobby  |  count |                    |  id  |  hobby  |  count |
---------------------------                    ---------------------------
|  1   |  Makan  |  1     |                    |  1   |  Makan  |  0     |
|  2   |  Renang |  0     |                    |  2   |  Renang |  0     |
|  3   |  Nyanyi |  1     |                    |  3   |  Nyanyi |  0     |
|  4   |  Youtube|  1     |                    |  4   |  Youtube|  0     |
|  5   |  Masak  |  0     |                    |  5   |  Masak  |  1     |
---------------------------                    ---------------------------
```

And so forth, how do I solve this problem?

This is my query that I write but doesn't seem to work, because only data with count greater than 0 is shown.

```
SELECT
    hobby.id,
    hobby.name,
    count( referensi.id ) AS count 
FROM
    referensi
    LEFT OUTER JOIN hobby ON hobby.id = referensi.ref_hobby
    JOIN person ON referensi.ref_person = person.id 
    WHERE person.id = 1
GROUP BY
    hobby.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to `JOIN` `referensi` to `person`, selecting only entries in `referensi` corresponding to the person of interest, and then `RIGHT JOIN` to `hobby`. If there is no matching entry, the output is 0, otherwise 1. For example, for person 1:

```
SELECT h.id, 
       h.hobby, 
       CASE WHEN r.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS count
FROM referensi r
JOIN person p ON p.id = r.ref_person AND p.id = 1
RIGHT JOIN hobby h ON h.id = r.ref_hobby
ORDER BY h.id
```

This can also be implemented with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT h.id, 
       h.hobby, 
       EXISTS (SELECT * FROM referensi r WHERE r.ref_hobby = h.id AND r.ref_person = 1) AS count
FROM hobby h
```

If a person/hobby tuple can appear in the `referensi` table more than once, you do need to do a `COUNT`:

```
SELECT h.id, 
       h.hobby, 
       COUNT(r.id) AS count
FROM referensi r
JOIN person p ON p.id = r.ref_person AND p.id = 1
RIGHT JOIN hobby h ON h.id = r.ref_hobby
GROUP BY h.id
```

Output (for all three queries on your sample data):

```
id  hobby       count
1   Makan       1
2   Renang      0
3   Nyanyi      1
4   Youtube     1
5   Masak       0
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2f511/20)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use condition aggravate function with `OUTER JOIN`

setting condition in `CASE WHEN`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    hobby.id,
    hobby.name,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN person.id = 3 THEN 1 END) AS count 
FROM
    hobby  
    LEFT JOIN referensi  ON hobby.id = referensi.ref_hobby
    LEFT JOIN person ON referensi.ref_person = person.id 
GROUP BY
    hobby.id,
    hobby.name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/631652/3/0)**:

```
| id |    name | count |
|----|---------|-------|
|  1 |   Makan |     0 |
|  2 |  Renang |     0 |
|  3 |  Nyanyi |     0 |
|  4 | Youtube |     0 |
|  5 |   Masak |     1 |
```

Comment: "aggravate" is how I often feel about MySQL, but I think you meant "aggregate"

Comment: All of answer is right, I dont know which answer should i choose. thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

You want to start your joining from `hobby` table, and use `LEFT JOIN`s to *optionnaly* bring up the matching records in other tables.

```
SELECT
    h.id,
    h.hobby,
    count( p.id ) AS count 
FROM
    hobby h
    LEFT JOIN referensi r ON h.id = r.ref_hobby
    LEFT JOIN person p ON r.ref_person = p.id AND p.id = 1
WHERE p.name is NULL OR p.name = 'Rose'
GROUP BY h.id, h.hobby
```

It is also a good practice to use table aliases, I added them to your query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vq6jqJWB26MQGhJZWXWsu9/1)** for user Rose :

```
| id  | hobby   | count |
| --- | ------- | ----- |
| 1   | Makan   | 1     |
| 2   | Renang  | 0     |
| 3   | Nyanyi  | 1     |
| 4   | Youtube | 1     |
| 5   | Masak   | 0     |
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer sir, but count still wrong because if I select Rose masak count value is 1.

Comment: @DennyKurniawan : ok, I double checked and fixed my answer. Also I added a db fiddle that demonstrates the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much sir, great answer. But I only want to select by person.Id only.